# Swift Core Data - Update Record key that is be using in NSSortDescriptor give a error

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I am using Core Data in my App and i add a NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate to a UITableViewController. Almost everything is working ok, except that if i update the key "serverName" in a record the application crash. I am using this key in my NSSortDescriptor. If i try to update any key that is be using by the NSSortDescriptor the app will crash.
The declaration of the NSFetchedResultsController is

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Hosts2")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "serverName", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        return fetchedResultsController
    }()
```

If i update the key that the NSSortDescription is using the .Move case it will run and then the app crash.

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        let section  = 2
        print("controller update \(indexPath) \(type) \n\(newIndexPath)")
        switch (type) {
        case .Insert:
            if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
                print("it will add new server")
                let myIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: section)
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([myIndex], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }
            break;
        case .Delete:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                print("it will delete the record")
                let myIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: section)
                self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([myIndex], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }
            break;
        case .Update:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                print("update in core data")
                let myIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: section)
                let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(myIndex) as! SetupShowHostsCell3TableViewCell
                configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
            }
            break;
        case .Move:
            print("did move")
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                let myIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: section)
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([myIndex], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }
            if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                let myIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: newIndexPath.row, inSection: section)
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([myIndex], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }
            break;
        }


    }
```

I can update any other key in any record. 
I am not posting the full code here because its to big, but i can do it if you guys ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you implemented `controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController)` and `controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController)` - they should do `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` respectively.

Comment: I totally forgot that man @pbasdf . Thank you very much. Its working now.